# Source of historic RFPs for the City of Chicago

Tags: city, chicago

The City of Chicago [lists current RFPs](http://www.cityofchicago.org/city/en/depts/dps/provdrs/contract/svcs/current_bid_opportunities.html). Is there a source for awarded RFPs before 2010?

Answer (score 4):

With the assumption that an RFP converts to a contract, they have an [Awarded Contract](http://www.cityofchicago.org/city/en/depts/dps/provdrs/contract/svcs/awarded_contracts.html) page. From there they have scanned documents for older content and a [Vendor, Contract and Payment Search](https://webapps1.cityofchicago.org/VCSearchWeb/org/cityofchicago/vcsearch/controller/agencySelection/begin.do) system which looks to have the Specification number for linking back to the RFP/RFQ/RFI

Given the edited questions request to find RFPs pre 2010, I have not been able to find a decent search capability but there is pre-2010 data in the system as evidenced by [Contract #13221](https://webapps1.cityofchicago.org/VCSearchWeb/org/cityofchicago/vcsearch/controller/contracts/display.do?contractNumber=13221). It was awarded in 2007